# ionic2: navigating between pages is very slow

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using `Ionic2`, I noticed that navigating between complex pages or opening complex page is very slow, Are there solutions for this problem
Note: complex pages means pages with large html and scss code this is an example

```js
import { ReviewPage } from '../review/review';
import { DescriptionPage } from '../description/description';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController, NavParams, PopoverController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
import { AppSettingsProvider } from '../../providers/app-settings/app-settings';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-product',
  templateUrl: 'product.html',
})
export class ProductPage {

  popvarOrderArr = ['Home','My Account','Cart','Wishlist','Specials'];
  productsArr:number[] = new Array(6) ;
  reviewsArr:number[] = new Array(2) ;    
  hashtagSliderArr:number[] = new Array(6) ;  
  contactModal;
  firstViewCtrl;
  rate = 3;
  

  constructor(public appSettingsProvider:AppSettingsProvider,public modalCtrl: ModalController,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,public viewCtr:ViewController,private socialSharing: SocialSharing) {
    console.log(this.getCurrentLAnguage());
  }

  starClicked(value){
    console.log("Avaliaram em :", value);
  }

  gotoDecriptionPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(DescriptionPage);
  }

  goToReviewsPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ReviewPage);
  }

  goToProductPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ProductPage);
  }

  share() {
    this.socialSharing.share('Hello World', 'Attention', null, 'https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com').then(() => {
      // Success!
    }).catch(() => {
      // Error!
    });
  }
  getCurrentLAnguage() {
    return this.appSettingsProvider.Language;
  }


}
```

```css
page-product {
    #firstCard {
        width: 100%;
        height: 44%;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #headerSlider {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        margin-top: 8%;
        img {
            width: 50%;
            height: 75%;
            margin-top: 10%;
            text-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            // left: 0;
            // right: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }
    ul {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        &.rating li {
            padding: 0px 0px !important;
            background: none;
            color: gold;
        }
    }
    #bottomSlider {
        margin-top: 4%;
        height: 40%;
        .slider .slider-pager {
            text-align: right;
        }
    }
    #addSpan {
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-left: 2%;
    }
    .sliderBtn {
        background-color: #c1eee1;
        color: #2fb991;
    }
    #checkoutBtn {
        background-color: #2fb991;
        color: white;
    }
    #productCard {
        margin-top: 3%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #oldPrice {
        text-decoration: line-through;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: gray;
    }
    #newPrice {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #productName {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #productNameslider {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #FgrayBtn,
    #SgrayBtn {
        color: gray;
        background-color: #f7f5fa;
    }
    #SgrayBtn {
        width: 10%;
    }
    #productDec {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    #grayTxt {
        color: gray;
    }
    #body {
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    .swiper-pagination-fraction,
    .swiper-pagination-custom,
    .swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
        left: 0;
        bottom: 80%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullets-active {
        color: red;
    }
    ion-content div.scroll-content {
        background-color: transparent;
        // opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .modal-wrapper {
        z-index: 10;
        height: 100%;
        // transform: translateY(55%);
    }
    .SMBtn {
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .optionName {
        font-size: 10px;
        color: gray;
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-header >
    <ion-navbar color="dark">
        <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>Product</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end mode="md" (click)="share()">
            <button ion-button icon-only no-padding no-margin>
                <ion-icon name="md-share"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons end mode="md" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
            <cart-icon no-padding no-margin></cart-icon>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons end mode="md" style="padding:0;margin:0;">
            <more-icon no-padding no-margin></more-icon>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content id="body">
    <ion-card no-padding no-margin id="firstCard" text-center>
        <div id="headerSlider">
            <img src="././assets/images/camera.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="bottomSlider">
            <ion-slides pager direction="horizontal" slidesPerView="3.0" spaceBetween="37" autoplay="3000" speed="3000">
                <ion-slide *ngFor="let product of hashtagSliderArr">
                    <button ion-button class="sliderBtn">PowerShot</button>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slides>
        </div>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card no-padding no-margin id="productCard">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <h2 id="productName">Canon Powershot SX60 HS</h2>
                <p>{{"AVIALABILITY" | translate}}:5</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item text-center>
                <div style="float:left;margin-left:15%;">
                    <span id="newPrice">100.900KD</span><br/>
                    <span id="oldPrice">119.900KD</span><br/>
                </div>
                <div style="float:right;margin-right:15%;">
                    <rating no-padding [(ngModel)]="rate" readOnly="true" max="5" emptyStarIconName="star-outline" halfStarIconName="star-half" starIconName="star" nullable="false" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"></rating>
                    
                    <p>(6){{"REVIEWS" | translate}}</p>
                </div>
                <ion-icon *ngIf="getCurrentLAnguage()=='en'" name="ios-arrow-forward" style="color:lightgray;" item-end></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon *ngIf="getCurrentLAnguage()=='ar'" name="ios-arrow-back" style="color:lightgray;" item-end></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item text-center>
                <button ion-button id="checkoutBtn">{{"CHECKOUT" | translate}}</button>
                <button ion-button id="FgrayBtn" icon-left><ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon><span id="addSpan">{{"ADDTOCART" | translate }}</span></button>
                <button ion-button text-center id="SgrayBtn" icon-only><ion-icon name="ios-heart"></ion-icon></button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card no-padding no-margin id="productCard">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                {{"DESCRIPTION" | translate }}
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col col-6 id="grayTxt">
                            {{"BRAND" | translate}}
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-6 id="productDec">
                            Canon
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col col-6 id="grayTxt">
                            {{"PRODUCTCODE" | translate }}
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-6 id="productDec">
                            Canon PowerShot SX60 HS
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-item>
            <hr/>
            <ion-item>
                <span text-wrap style="font-size:15px;">
                    Explore detail at a distace<br/>
                    Explore detail at a distace Explore detail at a distace Explore detail at a distace Explore detail at a distace Explore detail at a distace
                    Explore detail at a distace Explore detail at a distace Explore detail at a distace  Explore detail at a distace
                </span>
            </ion-item>
            <hr/>
            <ion-item text-center style="color:red;" (click)="gotoDecriptionPage()">
                {{"VIEWALL" | translate}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-card>

    <ion-card no-padding no-margin id="productCard">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                {{"REVIEWS" | translate}}(6)
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let review of reviewsArr">
                <ion-avatar item-start>
                    <img src="http://safe-pay.co/safepay/public/uploadedimg/user/avatar.png">
                </ion-avatar>
                <h2>Mai1234</h2>
                <p>23 jun 2014</p>
                <rating no-padding [(ngModel)]="rate" readOnly="true" max="5" emptyStarIconName="star-outline" halfStarIconName="star-half" starIconName="star" nullable="false" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"></rating>
                
                <span id="productDec">Exellent Very Good</span>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-card>

    <h5 style="padding-left:3%;padding-right:3%;margin-bottom:0;">{{"RELATEDPRODUCTS" | translate }}</h5>

    <ion-slides no-margin no-padding autoplay="3000" speed="3000" direction="horizontal" slidesPerView="2.1" spaceBetween="0" style="height:45%;">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let product of productsArr" (click)="goToProductPage()">
            <ion-card>
                <div>
                    <img src="././assets/icons/favorite.svg" align="right" style="margin-top:5%;margin-right:5%;float:right;width:11%;height:11%;" />
                </div>
                <ion-item>
                    <img src="././assets/images/camera.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;margin-left:30%;" />
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <div style="margin-right:4%;text-align:center">
                        <span id="productNameslider" no-wrap>Canon Power shot SX60 HS</span><br/>
                        <span id="oldPrice">119.900KD</span><br/>
                        <span id="newPrice">100.900KD</span><br/>
                        <rating no-padding [(ngModel)]="rate" readOnly="true" max="5" emptyStarIconName="star-outline" halfStarIconName="star-half" starIconName="star" nullable="false" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"></rating>                        
                    </div>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

this is one page that has many lines of code, other pages with less code is openned faster than those

Comment: In general navigating between pages is not slow in ionic. You need to provide more details on your implementation and tell us what you mean with complex page, if you want helpful replies

Comment: I mean that navigating  between pages with large html and scss code is very slow

Comment: ionic caches pages after first call, so general large html or css is probably not the root cause. But without code, you will not get help

Comment: I have already added it

Comment: how many items are in reviewsArr, productsArr and hashtagSliderArr

Comment: @schacki 6 items in productsArr and hashtagSliderArr & 2 in reviewsArr

Comment: why are you using ngFor anyway, there is actually nothing happing with the items, e.g. product. Is this real code? I do not see any reason why it should be slow

Comment: @schacki I'll use data from web service and i'll use ngFor

Comment: Try this navCtrl.push(PageName,{},{animate: false}) ;